# Lodash adding external brackets, need to remove

Tags: javascript, json, nested, lodash

I need some help in my code. Not sure why it's adding [ ] outside.

The output I need is

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "ABC111"
                },
                {
                    "v": 50,
                    "f": "50 inches"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "CDE222"
                },
                {
                    "v": 100,
                    "f": "100 inches"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "GHI333"
                },
                {
                    "v": 150,
                    "f": "150 inches"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, my code is wrapping everything inside [ ]. What should I fix in my code? Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c1tzt3er/

Comment: you might wanna map `dailyData.devices`? `map` always returns an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_.map()` function always returns an array. Just dereference element 0:

```
 output(JSON.stringify(result[0], undefined, 4));
```

[Fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/359cxse5/)

Comment: Ok Pointy, never thought of that. Although for juk's reply, I also tried dailyData.devices but was wondering why my output was returning the value true only.I'll try it again.